# What term means "all of the words one knows"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What term, ideally used by linguists, refers to the entire collection of words that a person knows? For example, if someone opened up a dictionary, and created a list of all of the words they know, what term would refer to that list?

Comment: There are two very important different types of "personal vocabulary" - [Receptive vs. Productive Vocabulary](http://www.visualthesaurus.com/cm/booknook/receptive-vs-productive-vocabulary/). There's also the concept of "Scrabble vocabulary" (for example, you might know all the 2-letter combinations valid in Scrabble, but have no idea what half of them actually mean).

Comment: @FumbleFingers My late father had just such a Scrabble Vocabulary. The one item of his possessions that was first to go to the charity shop was his dreadful 'Scrabble Word Book'.

Comment: @WS2: I still have *four* paper copies of OSW (1st - 4th Edition). Plus I'm fairly unique in that I "legitimately" have an electronic copy of OSW1. I used it when writing a crossword generator for a freelance editor/publisher (who was owed a favour by the copyright holder Chambers), and nobody ever told me I couldn't keep a copy afterwards.

Comment: I am not an English, but we call it word-stock. *How fluently you speak English depends on your **word-stock***

Comment: Receptive vs productive vocabulary is a useful distinction. However the dividing line is not always so clear. It may be useful to represent knowledge of a particular word along a continuum of increasing degrees of familiarity. We each have a large "grey zone" of words that we don't feel 100% confident in using but that we may be with repeated encounters.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You mean one's (personal) **vocabulary**?

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vocabulary) says:

> all of the words known and used by a person

Comment: Is there any confirmation that this is the term used by linguistics?

Comment: Is an article from [oxford journals](http://applij.oxfordjournals.org/content/19/2/255.abstract) under the heading of applied _linguistics_ good enough? Note that strictly speaking, you asked about the words a person _knows_, not the words a person _uses_. Your question refers to _passive vocabulary_, but that is two words, and the rules for SWRs are strict.

Comment: Yes, that is sufficient.

Answer (score 34):

I would use the word *lexicon*.

> *noun* the vocabulary of a person, language, or branch of knowledge.

Quoted from [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lexicon).

Comment: Or more specifically, a *mental lexicon*.

Comment: there is an academic journal that is called *The Mental Lexicon*.

Comment: This is the word that immediately came to mind, but vocabulary would seem to be just as correct.

Comment: i like this answer just as much as *vocabulary*, but i have to recommend *vocabulary* because you are FAR more likely to be understood.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a colloquial word for this: ***wordrobe***. It is like a wardrobe of words.

> a person's vocabulary
>
> *She reads dictionaries to build up her wordrobe.*
>
> <sub>http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wordrobe</sub>

Comment: sounds like something you'd wear rather than fill or reference.

Answer (score 2):

Also [word-hoard](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/word-hoard) ( from TFD)
:

> - (n.)  the sum of words one uses or understands; a vocabulary.
> - a person's vocabulary.

Answer (score 2):

**Vocabulary**, as already posted by @oerkelens, is the stock of words used by or known to a particular person.

> - "He has a somewhat limited [**vocabulary**."](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vocabulary)
> - "Reading will certainly help you expand your vocabulary."
> - "My wife has a wide vocabulary."

Comment: I guess 'vocabulary' is already in the list of the terms suggested!!

Comment: [@oerkelens' answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/209141/18696), complete with MW link, was posted as much as half an hour before this one. And you **must** [reference quotes in plain text](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), not merely via a link.

Comment: @AndrewLeach First let me apologize for posting an answer someone had already posted. I've edited and added the credit. As for "And you must reference quotes in plain text", I'm not sure I understand that. Do you mean: "He has a somewhat limited vocabulary". http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vocabulary ?  or simply "He has a somewhat limited vocabulary." Merriam Webster(in red, with link)? or another way?

Comment: `He has a somewhat limited [vocabulary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vocabulary)` with "[Merriam-Webster]" as plain text will do. [Meta post](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/new-attribution-rules/5196#5196)

Comment: @AndrewLeach With a bluish shade on the background? I'm afraid I don't know how to do that.

Comment: No, that's so that the link appears exactly how you type it. Have a read of the Meta post.

Answer (score 0):

idiolect: the variety or form of a language used by an individual 
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/idiolect?s=t

Comment: This is much wider than just the vocab though, as it includes the person's grammar.

Answer (score -2):

Another interesting word is schema, although that encompasses more than just the words which one knows.

Comment: Can you provide a definition and source? Looking through wiktionary and reference.com I don't see anything about words.